# k3s backups and snapshots not working well

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a k3s cluster for which I want to restore snapshots selectively. I start the cluster with:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s server - --cluster-init --token "1234" --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --disable traefik --data-dir=/home/user/etcd-backups --etcd-snapshot-retention=72 --etcd-snapshot-dir=/home/user/etcd-snapshots --etcd-snapshot-schedule-cron="*/5 * * * *"
```

then once there are some snapshots I do:

```
sudo k3s server  --cluster-reset  --cluster-reset-restore-path=/home/user/etcd-snapshots/etcd-snapshot-fanless-1683011104
```

but I then get:

```
FATA[0001] starting kubernetes: preparing server: init cluster datastore and https: listen tcp :6443: bind: address already in use
```

If I stop the cluster with:

```
/usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh
```

then it is not logically a reset anymore. But, even if I do execute the reset command after stopping the cluster the command doesn't complain itself but then something strange happens:

```
david ~ ~ : sudo chmod 777 /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
david ~ ~ : k get po
E0502 09:42:55.295292   39080 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6444/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6444: connect: connection refused
E0502 09:42:55.295587   39080 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6444/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6444: connect: connection refused
E0502 09:42:55.297040   39080 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6444/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6444: connect: connection refused
E0502 09:42:55.298438   39080 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6444/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6444: connect: connection refused
E0502 09:42:55.300339   39080 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6444/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6444: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6444 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Can somebody give a hand and provide some example that works? the K3s docs doesn't tell much about this important feature and the command is also not very explanatory when it gets executed

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the cluster with

```
systemctl stop k3s.service
```

And re-run the "cluster reset/restore command" you did in the second step
It should work, since `k3s.service` isn't using that port now
After that, start k3s again

```
systemctl start k3s.service
```

The cluster should be restored, and `kubectl` working properly :)